# Extracting ARM Boot zImage

Tags: firmware, arm

I'm trying to analyze the firmware of a system running Linux and connecting various home automation and security devices. Every time it boots, the [GM8125 processor](http://www.openipcam.com/files/ARM9/GM8126/GM8126%20v1.1/Docs/Datasheet/GM812X_Data_Sheet_V0.4.pdf) running ARMv5TE loads a firmware image from the [SPI flash](https://www.winbond.com/resource-files/w25q128jv%20spi%20revc%2011162016.pdf). I connected to the flash with a Bus Pirate and pulled off the firmware image. When I run `binwalk` on it, I get the following.

```
$ binwalk spidump.bin 

DECIMAL       HEXADECIMAL     DESCRIPTION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
271284        0x423B4         Sega MegaDrive/Genesis raw ROM dump, Name: "ETIR_ON", "ECCAS",
744708        0xB5D04         CRC32 polynomial table, big endian
786432        0xC0000         gzip compressed data, maximum compression, from Unix, last modified: 1970-01-04 16:05:57 (bogus date)
917760        0xE0100         Linux kernel ARM boot executable zImage (big-endian)
9306332       0x8E00DC        Zlib compressed data, compressed
9307424       0x8E0520        Zlib compressed data, compressed
9308196       0x8E0824        Zlib compressed data, compressed
9309036       0x8E0B6C        Zlib compressed data, compressed
9310040       0x8E0F58        Zlib compressed data, compressed
9310220       0x8E100C        Zlib compressed data, compressed
9311200       0x8E13E0        Zlib compressed data, compressed
9312104       0x8E1768        JFFS2 filesystem, little endian
9317132       0x8E2B0C        Zlib compressed data, compressed
9317428       0x8E2C34        JFFS2 filesystem, little endian
9318332       0x8E2FBC        Zlib compressed data, compressed
[...]
```

If I run `binwalk -Mre` it gives me nearly 6000 files and several hundred folders of the extracted `Zlib` and `JFFS2` data. After analyzing these, I thought I'd look at the boot image.

I carved out the zImage by running `dd if=spidump.bin of=carved.bin bs=1 skip=917760 count=8388572`. Running `file` returns `carved.bin: Linux kernel ARM boot executable zImage (big-endian)`.

So far so good. This is where I get lost.

From reading other posts here and elsewhere, it seems like I should search for the magic bytes of where compression starts--since this is big-endian, I run `objdump` with a lot of results (only the first few lines listed).

```
$ arm-none-eabi-objdump -EB -D -m armv5te -b binary carved.bin | grep 1f8b
    9b38:   1f8b3c36    svcne   0x008b3c36
   1f8b0:   bf2e3abe    svclt   0x002e3abe
   1f8b4:   0811cabb    ldmdaeq r1, {r0, r1, r3, r4, r5, r7, r9, fp, lr, pc}
   1f8b8:   baaee7f4    blt 0xfebd9890
   1f8bc:   fc3711aa    ldc2    1, cr1, [r7], #-680 ; 0xfffffd58
   20c38:   f3b1f8b9            ; <UNDEFINED> instruction: 0xf3b1f8b9
   233c0:   d1f8badf    ldrsble fp, [r8, #175]! ; 0xaf
   2c7d8:   011f8b05    tsteq   pc, r5, lsl #22
   2d990:   e9ff1f8b    ldmib   pc!, {r0, r1, r3, r7, r8, r9, sl, fp, ip}^  ; <UNPREDICTABLE>
```

I carve the file starting from the first occurrence of the magic bytes by running `dd if=carved.bin of=arm.gz bs=1 skip=39736`. `file` returns `arm.gz: gzip compressed data, unknown method, has CRC, extra field, has comment, encrypted, last modified: Mon Sep 15 08:57:49 1975` and `gunzip` refuses to unzip, saying `unknown method 60 -- not supported`. Most later occurrences of `1f8b` are not aligned at the beginning of a byte, so I assume they are not good candidates for carving and unzipping. It seems like the first occurrence, and subsequent occurrences, might just all be by chance.

Is this truly a zImage, or could `binwalk` and `file` be confused? How can I tell? How do I extract it?

Unfortunately, I can't provide the binary for your own perusal.

**Update - 6/25/2019**

I've included a graph of the entropy of the file, as requested by julian. It does look like the section in question is compressed.

[image: spidump_entropy]

**Update - 7/5/2019**

Upon further review with an expert, it seems like `binwalk` misidentified the type(s) of files. It looks like there is a custom unpacker I need to either disassemble or have it run and then take the unpacked image from memory.

Comment: I think I'm missing something; why are you trying to disassemble compressed data?

Comment: look at an entropy plot of the suspected zImage to determine whether it is compressed or not

Comment: @IgorSkochinsky I thought perhaps if the file structure didn't contain what I was looking for, the boot image would have more information about specific open ports and information associated with those ports.

Comment: @julian I added a plot of the entropy and it does look like it is legitimately compressed.

Comment: if a binwalk scan of the compressed data doesn't return any true/legitimate signatures you may need to go over a hex dump manually of the first few bytes of the data to look for anything info pointing to a particular compression algorithm.

Comment: have followed your method and get file zImageGzip
gzip compressed data, last modified: Sun Dec 7 19:20:31 2008, max compression, from Unix, original size modulo 2^32 0 7-Zip will unpack but returns saying "there are some data after the end of the payload data perhaps there is a tail section that is not compressed data, or some other format issue, I'm going to try stripping the back end of the file take 104 bytes off
dd if=zImage of=zImageData bs=8 skip=13 find first occurence of 0x1f8b it comes at 0x328c which is 12940
arm-none-eabi-objdump -EB -D -m armv5te -b binary zImageData | grep 1f8b ta